# Can not get <div> to open page using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find out why my button will not load the page correctly using the javascript.  I can't figure out if its CSS or a Javascript error and I've been staring at it to long for my mind to get round it.  Any help would be very much appreciated.

Below is the Javascript code:-

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function show_details(thisId) {
var deets = (thisId.id);
el = document.getElementById("overlay");
el.style.display = (el.style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block";
el = document.getElementById("events");
el.style.display = (el.style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block";
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url "Scripts/bookings.php";
var vars = "deets="+deets;
hr.open("POST", url, true);
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        var return_data = hr.responseText;
        document.getElementById("events").innerHTML = return_data;
    }
}
hr.send(vars)
document.getElementById("events").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
</script>
```

The CSS Sets:

```
body
{
height:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#overlay 
{
display:none;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
height:100%;
z-index:2000;
background: #000;
opacity: .9;
}

#events 
{
display: none;
width:500px;
border:4px solid #9C9;
padding: 15 px;
z-index:3000;
margin-top: 100px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left:auto;
background-color: #FFF;
height:400px;
overflow:scroll;
}

#eventControl 
{
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 30px;
z-index: 3000;
}

#eventBody 
{
display: block;
width: 100%;
z-index:3000;
}
```

The Call to Action Button:

```
<input name='$date' type='submit' value='Details' id='$date' onClick='javascript:show_details(this);'>
```

$date variable is set from the users choice selection.  I can post more code but I think the fault lies in the code provided.  Please do ask if you think otherwise.

Comment: The <DIV> Sets

<div id="overlay"><div id="events"></div></div>

Comment: So what does it look like? What's the actual problem?

Comment: @Manu Thanks for the response.  The call the action button doesn't work.  It does not load the bookings page within the div set.

Comment: Ok... So running debugger in chrome suggests show_details is not defined.

Comment: Please add a minimum runnable code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
var url "Scripts/bookings.php";
```

to

```
var url = "Scripts/bookings.php";
```

Also, your `el` variable is defined as a property of the function, i'd recommend using `var el`. Also use separate variables for your `document.getElementById`. Just to keep the next developer sane.

And you're calling `document.getElementById("events");` twice, just use the same variable the second time (in the callback function)

Comment: Ahh Thank You!  I have been staring at this for 2 hours!!!  Knew it would be something tupid I missed in haste!  Have a Merry Christmas!

Comment: No problem, would recommend using something like Dreamweaver or net-beans (what i use). A simple copy and paste threw up the error instantly. Merry Christmas yourself! p.s. accept the answer if it helped you.